# How/what to use onResume() or onStart in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

My app consists of 7 activities. For the first time when it has been installed in a device, I want to show all the activities. When the app has been closed and used later, I want a particular activity to be hidden. How to work out this? Please help me. If I have to use `onResume` or `onStart`, how to implement it?

Comment: By "activities" do you mean instances of the Android class Activity, or are you just using it in a general sense, as in something the user can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time your application is launched set a boolean values such as `isLaunched` to `true` using
[putBoolean()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), and then subsequently, when you launch the app, if [getBoolean](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) of `isLaunched` is `true`, don't show that particular Activity.

Comment: how to set a boolean value for this...pls help me

Comment: Take a look at [Using Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 1):

You can only show one activity at a time in Android. What were you trying to accomplish by showing seven activities at once? Look into using [Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) instead of activities. For more information on activities, take a look at the [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) (you'll have to scroll to get there).

Comment: i am not trying to show all the activities at a time.... Mr.Rajath Dsouza is able understand what i asked...anyhow thanx